# Rss feed not working in PHP

Tags: php, rss

In my webpage everything works except the rss feed. All the html code and scripts are loaded. But the rss feed is blank. I tried different formats but none is working. Please help. I used the code in seperate file as functions.php and called it in index.php

functions.php

```
<?php

function parserSide($feedURL) {
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    echo "<ul class='newsSide'>";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feedItem) {
        $i++;
        echo "<li><a href='$feedItem->link' title='$feedItem->title'>" . $feedItem->title . "</a></li>";
        if($i >= 5) break;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once('functions.php');
parserSide("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews"); ?>
```

Comment: It's working for me. Do you get any error?

Comment: No errors. Just left blank. It worked in my pc, but not in another machine.

Comment: Check error with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); `

Comment: Other machine has PHP5?

Comment: Yes , it has PHP5 only

Answer (score 1):

Can't see any problems, except that you're not checking the return value of `simplexml_load_file`. On failure, the function will return `FALSE` and most likely that is the case. Or, remote file access is disabled for your server as in here: [simplexml_load_file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529533/simplexml-load-file-not-working)?

Comment: I tried putting the function in the same file say index.php. Even that didnt work.

Comment: Is the other machine some shared host? If so, the remote file access can be disabled, but there should be some Warning messages, provided the error reporting is enabled. What's the output of var_dump(parserSide(...))?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `return` instead of `echo` in function
2. Make sure `functions.php` file included

#### functions.php

```
function parserSide($feedURL) {
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    $output = "<ul class='newsSide'>";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($rss->channel->item as $feedItem) {
        $i++;
        $output .= "<li><a href='$feedItem->link' title='$feedItem->title'>" . $feedItem->title . "</a></li>";
        if($i >= 5) break;
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";

    return $output;
}
```

#### index.php

```
require_once('functions.php');

echo parserSide("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews");
```

Comment: Tried with return too. no changes. still the page is blank.